# WPF графические примитивы

Tags: wpf, графика, xaml

Нужно с помощью графических примитивов сделать различные диаграммы(столбчатая и круговая) и нарисовать часы. Использую WPF.
Подскажите в какую сторону рыть и куда ковырять?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар говорит, что вам нужны `UserControl`'ы.

Comment: Расплывчатая формулировка. Если хотите именно рисовать, то [Geometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно Ватсон - надо рыть в сторону [графических примитивов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx) которые являются производными от класса Shape.

В данном случае Вас будут интересовать Line+Ellipse(часы), Rectangle и Path(для круговой диаграммы).

Answer (score 1):

Копать надо в сторону примеров, коих полно. Нужные графические примитивы из WPF -  Ellipse, Line, Rectangle, Path, Polygon, для которых можно использовать заливки (Fill), штрихи (Stroke), кисти (Brush).

[Analog Clock in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29438/Analog-Clock-in-WPF)

[WPF Charting using MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117673/WPF-Charting-using-MVVM-Pattern)